# Why is reputation not awarded for helpful flags?

Tags: discussion, reputation, flags

I would like to know, why on Stack Exchange sites we don't currently get reputation for helpful flags?

It could perhaps be awarded with the same amount of rep that an edit is worth (+2 per helpful flag, perhaps up to 1000 rep total like edits).

Comment: The more important question is why is reputation not awarded to those that *process* the flags?